# Rewinding a file pointer

Tags: c, file, pointers

I know that you can just close a file but I wanted to try and use rewind function, but I'm getting an odd error. First I read a file and count the number of words and then I try and rewind(just to practice doing file processing), and the following error is output: Looks like the problem is with the last line of code.

https://snag.gy/63oqwC.jpg

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readFile(FILE  *f, char *fileName) {
    int count = 0;
    char ch;

    f = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if ( f == NULL ) {
        printf("Cannot open %s file, please verify it's in the right location\n", fileName);
    }

    while ( (ch = fgetc(f) ) != EOF ) {
        if ( ch == '\n' ) {
            count++;
        }

    }
    printf("The count number is %d", count);
    return count;

}


int main() {

FILE *wordInput = NULL;
    int i, j, k = 0;
    char c;
    char *point; // pointer that points to a word
    char **dictionary; // pointer that points to variable point
    int count = 0;
    int dictChoice; // which dictionary are they picking
    int numLetters = 4; // number of letters for each word

    FILE *fPoint = NULL;


    char *name = "smallDictionary.txt";

    readFile(wordInput, name);

    rewind(wordInput);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got rid of the close statement and it still does it

Comment: C is pass by value. `wordInput` in `main()` is initialised to `NULL` and does never change its value.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to realise that `readFile` does not pass to main the file pointer?

Comment: BTW, `fgetc()` returns `int` not `char`.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much. Also the fgetc() thing, why would that matter?

Comment: To be able to read 256 different characters and as well be able to return a separate value to identify end-of-file on top of those 8 bit simply are not sufficient.

Comment: "*that's not working*" means exactly what? How do you test? What happens?

Comment: @alk I accidentally left the fclose line, when I took it off it worked. So it's working, thanks.

Comment: Note that `fopen()` returns the `FILE *` value that you're to use.  Your function is supposed to give `main()` a `FILE *` it can use, it seems (the rewind operation needs a valid `FILE *` and doesn't get one yet).  Maybe your function should follow `fopen()`'s lead?

Answer (score 1):

```
int readFile(FILE *f, char *fileName)
```

Since you are trying to modify a `FILE` pointer, you will need to pass a pointer to a pointer to `FILE`, or `FILE **`. Change the function header to

```
int readFile(FILE **f, char *fileName)
```

In the caller, you will need to pass a pointer to a `FILE *` object:

```
FILE *pf;
int n = readFile(&pf, "filename.txt");
```

Also, when you are done manipulating the file, call `fclose` immediately

```
fclose(pf);
```